# IIS access to a remote server in same domain

Tags: php, python, iis

I have a server `A` where some logs are saved, and another server `B` with a web server (`IIS`) on it.

I can access `serverA` from `Windows Explorer` with zero problems, but when I want to access it from `serverB` with some `PHP` code, it doesn't work.

I made a `python` script that accesses the file from `serverA` on `serverB`. It works if I run that script from `CMD`, but when I run that script from `PHP` code it doesn't work anymore.

I run `IIS` server as a domain account that has access on `serverA`

I try to run that as `LocalService`, `NetworkService`, `System`, `LocalUser` but no success.

That script is a simple open command, so problem it's not from `python`.

Comment: What does the `PHP` code that is calling the `python` script look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.
Uninstall IIS and use XAMPP.
No problem found till now, everything works okay.
So use XAMPP/WAMP!

Answer (score 0):

Since you provide no example code or describe what you are doing... There are a few things to consider.

1. Anything running in the context of a webpage in IIS is running in a different context than a logged in user.
2. The first part of that is simply what file system level permissions might be different for the IIS user account. The proper way you want to handle that is by assigning the necessary changes at the filesystem level for the IIS user. Do not change the IIS user if you do not understand the ramifications of doing that.
3. The next part is that certain operations cannot be done in the context of the IIS user account (regardless of account permissions), because there are certain things that only a logged in user with access to the console/desktop can do.
4. Certain operations called from IIS are purposely blocked (shell.execute) regardless of permissions, account used, etc. This occurs in versions of IIS in Windows Server 2008 and later and is done for security.